# Imager. Download corrupt. Hash does not match

Tags: sd-card, raspberry-pi-imager

I'm trying to create an SD card with Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64-bit). It writes up to 196% and then gives an error "The download is corrupted. The hash does not match." Is the SD card died?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried downloading the image from the website again? What computer are you using to flash the image?

Comment: @CoderMike, I tried to install one of the old images from the computer and the installation was successful. I'm using a Windows PC. Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz. RAM 16 GB.

Comment: Try downloading the latest image again.

Comment: @CoderMike today it worked. Maybe it's a temporary local problem or a heisenbug. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `a heisenbug` shakes fist at cats :p no, wait, that's Schrödinger